# line break in option select dropdown

Tags: forms, element

Just wondering if there is a simple workaround for :

putting ----------------
as an option in a dropdown select box ( or just a whitespace ) 
That users cant select ?

Like:

```
<option value="1">choice a</option>
<option value="2">choice b</option>
<option value="3">--------</option>
<option value="4">choice c</option>
<option value="5">choice d</option>
```

Tried adding value="null" to no avail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<OPTGROUP>` to group various options together.

```
<optgroup label="First group">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Second group">
  etc...
<optgroup>
```

That would give you something like

```
First group
   1
   2
   3
Second group
   4
   5
```

in the dropdown, and the labels wouldn't be selectable.

Comment: I am a knob, I am using optgroup aswell lol. Hadnt considered that, cheers works perfect